# Python: pivot_table and groupby get totally opposite result

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I am dealing with the dataset **titanic** from [*seaborn*].

```
titanic = seaborn.load_dataset('titanic')
```

I cut the age column into categorical bins.

```
age = pd.cut(titanic['age'], [0, 18, 80])
```

Then the problem comes, the groupby and pivot_table give totally different results:

```
titanic.groupby(['sex', age, 'class'])['survived'].mean().unstack(-1)
titanic.pivot_table('survived', ['sex', age], 'class')
```

[groupby and pivot_table results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ecd9.png)

At first, I guess it is because the nan in **age**, then I used dataset processed by dropna to redo it.

```
titanic = titanic.dropna()
age = pd.cut(titanic['age'], [0, 18, 80], right = True)
titanic.groupby(['sex', age, 'class'])['survived'].mean().unstack(-1)
titanic.pivot_table('survived', ['sex', age], 'class')
```

This time I even got a totally different result.

[groupby and pivot_table results after dropna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6757L.png)

My python version is:Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
pandas: 0.23.0

My operating system is MaxOS High Sierra 10.13.6

I tried again with python 3.7.0 and pandas 0.23.4, and no error occurs.

[result under python 3..7.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maLu2.png)

So I am wondering whether it is a bug of Anaconda?

Comment: I have tried many times, this bug only occurs under Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc. pandas: 0.23.0

Comment: And if you create a new environment with Python 3.6.6:: Anaconda, Inc. pandas:0.23.4, this bug disappears.

Comment: I finally found out that it is a bug of pandas, which appeared in 0.23.0 version and was solved in 0.23.4 version.

Comment: Because you resolved your problem you should write an aswer to your question and accept it. This way your question will show as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is a bug of pandas, which appeared in 0.23.0 version, released in May 2018, and was solved in 0.23.4 version, released in Sep 2018.

So if you happens to meet some problems concerning pandas.pivot_table, especially when the there exist NaNs in your categorical data, you'd better first check your pandas version and upgrade it.:)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your statements and am getting matching results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6vo1.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me your Python version and Pandas version?

Comment: I tried again in the command line with python 3.7.0, and the result matches. Then I think there is something wrong with anaconda:(